# How to turn off texture painting mode where your brush cursor lags behind your mouse position?

Tags: texture-painting

I'm playing around with learning how to paint textures in blender, and must have somehow enabled a strange drawing mode that causes the drawing head of my brush to lag behind the place where I'm actually drawing the stroke.

I was able to paint normally earlier.  Now when I draw a stroke, there's this line from the center of my cursor to a point where my brush was earlier, and the stroke is drawn there.  It makes painting much harder and I can't figure out how to turn it off.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I turned Smooth Stroke on.  Once I unchecked that, I went back to the regular painting mode.
The smooth stroke option is found in the *Tool Shelf* > *Tools* tab > *Stroke* section.
[image: stroke options]

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut to toggle this on and off is Shift-S(Smooth Stroke). It sometimes can be toggled by accident if the user presses S to sample a color a few times and accidentally presses Shift.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce Input Samples. [image: Stroke]

Or turn off smooth stroke. It can be either of them.

Answer (score 0):

In newer Blender 2.93 it is Stabalize stroke, uncheck the box.

Tool Shelf > Tools tab > Stroke section>Stabalize stroke.

Still same short cut Shift + S.

[image: Sabilize stroke to be turned off]