# reassign Pen's Eraser end drawing mode

Tags: texture-painting

my drawing tablet's pen has two end - one works as a pen and the other one as eraser. thing is, Blender can't do anything with Eraser end - i've read it is supposed to work as Erase Alpha, but it does nothing but displaying red circle and a dotted line around it while attempting to draw. it also doesn't change anything about the brush settings.

so, is there a way to either prevent Blender from changing Eraser end's mode or select what mode will be used?

drawing with the "normal" drawing end:
[image]

drawing with the "eraser" end:
[image]

both screenshots were taken while pen was pressing on tablet

Comment: You could show some screenshots of what happens when you draw, but *" displaying red circle and a dotted line around it while attempting to draw"* reminds me of Smooth Stroke enabled,  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22886/how-to-turn-off-texture-painting-mode-where-your-brush-cursor-lags-behind-your-m.

Comment: @Zak added screenshots. it looks a bit different and there's no white line behind the cursor

Comment: I think it's the grease-pencil eraser.  You might need software to remap the tablet eraser as keyboard input, then assign a shortcut in Blender to whatever keypress you decide upon.

Comment: If you are painting into a solid color in an image that is not transparent, I recommend setting your second color there instead of black to the solid color your canvas is - that way, toggle X to shift from paint color to canvas color as 'eraser'. Using erase Alpha in the image you show would leave transparent areas that would then need to be painted in. Using Erase Alpha also pairs with Add Alpha, enabling you to reintroduce paint that was lost when you used Erase Alpha.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Okay I finally figured out how to make a shortcut to an eraser for Texture Paint.

The idea is that I needed to figure out the correct function id for the Blend modes (MIX + Erase-Alpha) and input that into the custom keymap menu

But usually when using digital art software for drawing you can have an eraser key that will erase only when pressed.

So I made 2 different keymaps one change to Erase-Alpha when Pressed and the other to switch back to Mix when Released.

This basically restore my workflow and avoid so much frustration while Texture painting.

Go in the *Preferences > Keymaps > 3d View > Image Paint*.
Go on the bottom and create a new key slot by pressing : *Add New* then click on the little arrow next to none to open the tab of the shortcut

Then in the field where its written `none` type `wm.context_toggle_enum`.

New fields will appear, in *Context Attribute*, type `tool_settings.image_paint.brush.blend`

In the first *Value* field, type `ERASE_ALPHA`.

And in the second, type `MIX`

Now set a key for your shortcut and set the key mode to : *Press*

Repeat the whole operation a second type (create another keymap in the same place) but this time, revert the 2 Values

First `MIX`

Second `ERASE_ALPHA`

Set the same key as before, but this time set it to *Release*

That way you will be able to erase only while holding the eraser key, but you can also simply make only one keymap and click it to switch between modes.